# How can I get the list of days of each month in the "JODA" library?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jodatime

I need to get a list of days each month in the JODA library. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Using *java.time*, the successor to [Joda-Time](http://lengthOfMonth).

```
yearMonth               // An instance of `java.time.YearMonth`.
.atDay( 1 )             // Returns a `LocalDate` object for the first of the month.
.datesUntil(            // Get a range of dates.
    yearMonth
    .plusMonths( 1 )    // Move to the following month.
    .atDay( 1 )         // Get the first day of that following month, a `LocalDate` object.
)                       // Returns a stream of `LocalDate` objects.
.toList()               // Collects the streamed objects into a list.
```

For older versions of Java without a `Stream#toList` method, use `collect( Collectors.toList() )`.

## *java.time*

The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance mode. The project recommends moving to its successor, the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 and built into Java 8 and later. Android 26+ has an implementation. For earlier Android, the latest Gradle tooling makes most of the *java.time* functionality available via « API desugaring ».

## `YearMonth`

Specify a month.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now() ;
```

Interrogate for its length.

```
int lengthOfMonth = ym.lengthOfMonth() ;
```

## `LocalDate`

To get a list of dates, get the first date of the month.

```
LocalDate start = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;
```

And the first day of the *next* month.

```
LocalDate end = ym.plusMonths( 1 ).atDay( 1 ) ;
```

Get a stream of dates in between. Collect into a list.

```
List< LocalDate > dates = start.datesUntil( end ).toList() ;
```

Comment: My minimum version is 21. java.time has an error about it

Comment: @saeednoshadi As I said, you need to use the latest Gradle tooling. Search on “API desugaring” to learn more. If that does not work for you, add the Android adaptation of the back-port, in the *ThreeTenABP* library.

Comment: Can I get the list of months' names with DateTime class?

Comment: @saeednoshadi [`Month#getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)). I suggest you spend some time perusing the *java.time* classes. And read the free tutorial by Oracle.